# Mercurial, cloning locally

Tags: mercurial

I have managed to clone my repository locally via the TortoiseHG gui. What i would like to know is how to do this via the command prompt. In TortoiseHG's clone window, there is a Hg command line containing the following:

> hg clone --verbose -- C:...\Mercurial Demo\Shared C:...\Mercurial Demo\Bob

Ive tried copying this into the command prompt but it doesnt work. It states the clone command should follow the following structure:

> hg clone [OPTION]... SOURCE [DEST]
>
> hg clone help wasnt any help either.

id appreciate it if someone could show me an example of how this should be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My overwhelming suspicion is that the path has spaces in it, so Mercurial is seeing far too many options. Try enclosing the paths in quotes.

Comment: I don't have a PC handy, but I believe PowerShell takes either, cmd.exe needs double quotes.

Comment: General note, i could only get it to work with double quotes.

Comment: Quoting on Windows is weird, because the application parses it, whereas on Unix, the OS does (see [CommandLineToArgv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) if you're curious for details).  That makes it hard for me to guess sometimes what any individual situation is going to take.